# Trouble inserting a javascript variable into an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-card

I have a URL for my site that looks like this: http://mysite.co/twittercard.html#johnsmith

I need to grab the text after the hash(`#`) in the URL, and use it in a `meta tag`.

I have been trying to insert the text into the `meta tag` like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="app" />
document.write('<meta name="twitter:description" content="' + window.location.hash + ' test sentence goes here!" />');
<meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:swift:name" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="testscheme://action/982y9hf92f92" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="testscheme://action/892ruhf92hf9" />
</head>
</html>
```

I have even tried using an extra `javascript` variable instead of just using `window.location.hash`:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="app" />
document.write('<meta name="twitter:description" content="' + username + ' test sentence goes here!" />');
<meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:swift:name" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="testscheme://action/982y9hf92f92" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="testscheme://action/892ruhf92hf9" />
</head>
var username = window.location.hash
</html>
```

But that doesn't work either. Any time I test this, the text that is displayed to the user is `"'+username+' test sentence goes here!"` or `"'+window.location.hash+' test sentence goes here!"`.

If my URL is `http://mysite.co/twittercard.html#johnsmith`, then I need the sentence to be displayed as: `"johnsmith test sentence goes here!"`.

EDIT:

I have added the script tags, and it is still not working:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="app" />
<script>
document.write('<meta name="twitter:description" content="' + window.location.hash + ' test sentence goes here!" />');
</script>
<meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:swift:name" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="testscheme://action/982y9hf92f92" />
<meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="App name" />
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id0923804893204" />
<meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="testscheme://action/892ruhf92hf9" />
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to wrap JS code in `<script>` tags

Comment: Do you think you might be missing your `<script>` tags in there?

Comment: whatever is trying to read said meta tag likely isn't executing javascript.

Comment: @KevinB I am using the Twitter card validator at https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator and for whatever reason it just doesn't want to display a preview of the text. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: also `window.location.hash` will return `#johnsmith` not jonsmith

Comment: hardcode it. If it works hardcoded and not with the edit you provided, then hardcoding it or using server-side code is the only option. if it doesn't work hardcoded, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @KevinB it works hardcoded. Looks like server side is the only option. Just found this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467730/dynamically-adding-meta-tags-using-javascript-or-jquery-twitter-cards