# How to dynamically update Twitter meta tags using Django model object fields

Tags: django, twitter, meta-tags

all. I am trying to create Twitter cards dynamically by filling in "content=" values with Django model object fields that I can update using the admin panel. My HTML header code looks like this:

```
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="{{ lesson.twitter_card_type }}">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ lesson.twitter_description }}">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ lesson.twitter_title }}">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="{{ lesson.twitter_site }}">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ lesson.twitter_image }}">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="{{ lesson.twitter_creator }}">
```

Replacing the variables with static values passes the Twitter card validator checks. When using variables, the browser inspector displays the proper meta tags, but I get the following output from the Twitter card validator log:

INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  13 metatags were found
ERROR: Invalid card name (Card error)

According to this answer [Twitter card meta tags work in index.html, not in React Helmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222217/twitter-card-meta-tags-work-in-index-html-not-in-react-helmet) and this answer [Dynamically adding meta tags using javascript or jquery [twitter cards]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467730/dynamically-adding-meta-tags-using-javascript-or-jquery-twitter-cards), it seems that there might be an issue using variables in meta tags; however, this site https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/how-to-add-django-meta-tags states using Django model objects should work.

Unfortunately, I need to create cards dynamically the way my site is set up so hard-coding is not an option. Thanks in advance to anyone who can offer any insight!